# Adding a figure created in a function to another figure's subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, subplot, figure

I created two functions that make two specific plots and returns me the respective figures:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(1,100)
y = range(1,100)

def my_plot_1(x,y):
    fig = plt.plot(x,y)
    return fig

def my_plot_2(x,y):
    fig = plt.plot(x,y)
    return fig
```

Now, outside of my functions, I want to create a figure with two subplots and add my function figures to it. Something like this:

```
my_fig_1 = my_plot_1(x,y)
my_fig_2 = my_plot_2(x,y)

fig, fig_axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=1)
fig_axes[0,0] = my_fig_1
fig_axes[0,1] = my_fig_2
```

However, just allocating the created figures to this new figure does not work. The function calls the figure, but it is not allocated in the subplot. Is there a way to place my function figure in another figure's subplot?

Comment: Probably better to pass an `Axes` to your function: `def my_plot_1(x, y, ax):`, `ax.plot(x, y)`

Comment: Could you expand on this? How would I use this `Axes` later in the main figure? My original function uses `Axes`, but I would like to send everything to the main figure. My function also modifies font size and other things, and I wanted to keep everything in the main figure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eaiser and better to just pass your function an `Axes`:

```
def my_plot_1(x, y, ax):
    ax.plot(x, y)

def my_plot_2(x, y, ax):
    ax.plot(x, y)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=1)

# pass the Axes you created above
my_plot_1(x, y, axs[0])
my_plot_2(x, y, axs[1])
```

Comment: I'm finding a small problem. One of my functions create a figure with a colorbar. I'm not able to carry this colorbar with me, since there is no figure. The following error occurs `No mappable was found to use for colorbar creation. First define a mappable such as an image (with imshow) or a contour set (with contourf)`. Any thoughts?

Comment: It may make more sense to ask that as a new question with a relevant code snippet, so that we can provide the best answer.