# Returning a colorbar in a function that does not call a figure

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, graph, colorbar

I asked how I could add a figure created in a function to another figure's subplot. This question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65618035/adding-a-figure-created-in-a-function-to-another-figures-subplot/65618282?noredirect=1#comment116016439_65618282) and is working alright. The problem is that one of the functions created a figure with a colorbar in it. Since the function is now returning only the `Axes` object, I'm not able to create the colorbar anymore and bring it with me to add to the main figure. The following error occurs:

`No mappable was found to use for colorbar creation. First define a mappable such as an image (with imshow) or a contour set (with contourf)`

The plot function that I'm using is like this:

```
def my_plot_1(x,y,ax):
    ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, cmap='jet')
    cbar = plt.colorbar()
    cbar.set_label('# of points', fontsize=14)
    cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize='12')
```

And is being used in the main figure like this:

```
fig, fig_axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=1)
my_plot_1(x, y, fig_axes[0])
```

Since there was a figure, it used to work fine. Now that I don't have the figure anymore, because the main figure is outside the function, it's not working. What could I do?

Comment: [Seems similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784201/matplotlib-2-subplots-1-colorbar). Otherwise, [`plt.colorbar`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html) has an `ax` parameter.

Comment: `ax.plot(x, y, c=z, cmap='jet')` doesn't produce a mappable for colorbar. Do you mean `ax.scatter`?

Comment: Yes @QuangHoang, I corrected that. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @BigBen, I want a different colorbar for each subplot. They have different numbers on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catch the mappable produced by `scatter`, then pass to `plt.colorbar`:

```
# your function doesn't have z
def my_plot_1(x,y,z,ax):
    mappable = ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, cmap='jet')
    cbar = plt.colorbar(mappable, ax=ax)
    cbar.set_label('Número de pontos', fontsize=14)
    cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize='12') 
    
fig, fig_axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=1)
my_plot_1([0,1],[0,1], [0,0.4], fig_axes[0])
fig.tight_layout()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: And pass `ax` as well to `colorbar`, which you did but just highlighting since that seems to also be a problem of OP.

Comment: You can also do `ax.figure.colorbar()` if you like.  A likely improvement for matplotlib is a `colorbar` method attached to axes.