# Displaying two SHAP beeswarm plots side by side in the same figure using matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, machine-learning, shap

I wonder how to place two independent SHAP beeswarm plots into the same figure but in different axes. I am using matplotlib version `3.4.2`, shap version `0.39.0`, and Python `3.8.2`. I am trying using a single figure and two axes but realize that the beeswarm method does not handle the axis as parameter (error: `TypeError: beeswarm() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ax'`).

I am aware of this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70696896/how-to-add-already-created-figures-to-a-subplot-figure), but this is different since I am using SHAP API. Any recommendation is welcome. Thanks in advance.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import shap

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(35, 7), gridspec_kw = {"wspace":1.0}) 

shap.plots.beeswarm(explainer_a(X_test_a), max_display=10, ax=axes[0])
shap.plots.beeswarm(explainer_b(X_test_b), max_display=10, ax=axes[1])

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import shap

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
shap.plots.beeswarm(explainer_a(X_test_a), max_display=10)
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
shap.plots.beeswarm(explainer_a(X_test_b), max_display=10)

# Optional for adjusting the margins:
plt.subplots_adjust(
    left=1,
    bottom=0.1, 
    right=3, 
    top=0.9
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution from @joao-pedro-macalos is almost complete, I just needed to add `show=False` to `beeswarm`.
Anyway I try to provide a complete solution here (tested on shap==0.44.1).

```
import shap
import xgboost as xgb
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create a mock dataset
X, y = shap.datasets.adult()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Train a model
model = xgb.XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Compute SHAP
explainer = shap.Explainer(model, X_train)
shap_values_test = explainer(X_test[:500])
shap_values_train = explainer(X_train[:500])

# Plot
# (credit to @joao-pedro-macalos )
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
shap.plots.beeswarm(
    shap_values_test, max_display=10, show=False)
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
shap.plots.beeswarm(
    shap_values_train, max_display=10, show=False)

# Optional for adjusting the margins:
plt.subplots_adjust(
    left=1,
    bottom=0.1, 
    right=3, 
    top=0.9
```